# Is the reference return of reference static variable in this example safe?

Tags: c++

I came across the code example below, and I am a bit confused. Is it safe to return a reference to the static reference variable like that?

```
static const defValue = 0;

const std::string& f(const int n)
{
    static std::string& str = std::to_string(defValue);
    ...
    // str might be changed here

    return str;
}
```

If it is safe, can someone tell me why? If it is not safe, why the compiler does not complain about it?

Comment: Please do post **the real code**. Thanks.

Comment: `std::to_string` does not return a reference (C++14 § 21.3, 21.5/7). The fact that you declare `str` to be one does not really matter here - changing it has no effect on `defValue`.

Comment: @simon: re "not complain", assuming you're using Visual C++, up the warning level via option `/W4`. might also be a good idea to ask it to treat warnings as errors, option `/WX`. the corresponding options with g++ are `-Wall -Wextra` for the warning level and `-pedantic-errors` to treat warnings as errors.

Comment: Hmm, as predicted, here I get a down vote of -3. As I read from other new SO members comments, new members post attracts down volts, without obvious reason. I posted a very basic C++ question here and I've checked this has not been posted before I posted it, and I've got a down vote for unknown reason. Could the down voter explains to me the reason of the down vote? Basic questions or dumb questions not allowed? I am still learning how to survive here. What an experience.

Comment: Thanks to all made comments here. You all made good valid points.

Comment: @Alf, I cannot post the real code as it violates the confidentiality of my work place. The posted function was partial rewritten of a class method. When I first read that method, my knowledge told myself what most comments here said. Tomorrow I shall post more in the "str might be changed here" that changed my perception of this piece of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example is invalid, as it makes a reference to the return value from `std::to_string`, which is a temporary value - by making it a reference, it is "kept alive" until the end of the scope of the reference (assuming it compiles at all - Standard C++ doesn't allow this construct), but other than that, it's still a local variable, so returning `str` will return a reference to a local variable.

If you alter it to be:

```
static std::string str = std::to_string(defValue);
```

so `str` itself is a static `std::string` object, then a copy of the result of `to_string` will be stored [using RVO to eliminate the actual copy, so no real overhead]. Then returning a reference to `str` is safe and correct [just beware that all callers of `f` will get exactly the same `str` [although it is returned as `const`, it's technically valid to cast it back to non-const and modify the value in this case, since the original reference is to a non-const object]

Comment: I don't get why you said : "just beware that all callers of f will get exactly the same str", because according to the standard : 
Static variables declared at block scope are initialized the first time control passes through their declaration. On all further calls, the declaration is skipped.

Comment: “by making it a reference, it is "kept alive" until the end of the scope of the reference”, no. Can't bind an rvalue to reference to non-`const`. Possibly it's Visual C++ that's accepting this (part of the) code, I haven't checked.

Comment: @Pumkko: Yes, so the compiler will [arrange to] construct `str` on the first call, and on subsequent calls, it will re-use the same object for `str`, but any caller that uses the string as a reference, will have to accept that a) it's the SAME string-object as other callers to `f` gets, and consequently, b) it may change at any time (quite likely in a non-threadsafe way as well)

Comment: @MatsPetersson Ah ok that's what you meant, totally agree

Comment: Returning a reference to a local variable is not (technically) an issue if said variable is static. Did OP change the question ?

Comment: @Quentin: Assuming this code at all compiles, `str` is a static REFERENCE to a temporory. It is not a `static` object, it's only the reference that is `static` - which does not make it safe to return.

Comment: @MatsPetersson I just tried it, and the reference does extend the lifetime of the temporary as a standard const reference does.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: Do note that the OP has not presented the real code, so whether the reference part compiles is a pretty moot issue. :( We can't know whether it's like that in the real code.

Comment: @Quentin Not in standard C++.

Comment: @juanchopanza of course (it wouldn't even compile), that's why I tried it (http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net is quite handy here)

Comment: @Quentin OK, so you tried it with a non-standards compliant compiler. What is your point?

Comment: @juanchopanza It is to my knowledge the only compiler which accepts this code at all, and its behaviour is to extend the lifetime of the temporary to that of the reference, which makes it safe to return. There are good reasons to avoid compiler bugs... errr... extensions, but is it to say we're not allowed to talk about them at all ?

Comment: @Quentin OK I see. Well, it compiles, but one would have to look up the semantics somewhere in the compiler's documentation. That is one of the problems with these "extensions".

Comment: @juanchopanza: the code does not compile with that online compiler (although the single statement in question does, with a warning); the code that's posted is just not the real code, it won't compile with any extant compiler. i.e., no, we have not left Herb Schildt-land. we're still here, surrounded by mainly Schildtren.

Comment: @MatsPeterson Thanks to your answer and all other who comments. I should up vote your answer. But as you see I am a new member and have no permission to up vote any answer. I can only say thank you for your time to post your answer.

Comment: @simon: You should be able to "accept" the answer, which will indicate to others that "this question has had a satisfactory answer" (and give me some rep-points)

Comment: @MatsPeterson: thanks for pointer out that. I am still learning how to use the system.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is a danger piece of code by looking the first line of the function. That is my gut feel and I posted the question to ask for confirmation of my gut feel. After posting the question, I read the real code carefully, and found it might not be what I thought.

The first line of the function serves as the initialization of the reference variable declaration and must be initialized with something for a reference variable declaration. C++ does not allow reference variable declared without initialization. In the "str might be changed here", it does something like below (again not real code):

```
const std::string& Cls::Mtd(const int n)
{
    static std::string& last = std::to_string(defValue);
    ...
    // str might be changed here
    auto itr = stringMap.find[n];
    if (stringMap.end() == itr)
    {
        stringMap.insert(std::pair<int, std::string>(n, last));
    }
    last = stringMap[n];

    return last;
}
```

This is a piece of pseudo code I craft to explain what the real code roughly doing. In the real code, the stringMap is a heap allocated complex data structure.
So I jumped to conclusion too fast and posted the question I asked. Alf is right about asking the real code before making comment and that I go back to read the real code.